# When is a continuous function piecewise monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given a continuous function $f:[a,b]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, are there known additional conditions that ensure $f$ is piecewise monotone?

Like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/decomposition-of-a-continuous-function-with-monotone-functions), my motivation is to decompose the interval $[a,b]$ as disjoint union of countable subintervals such that $f$ is monotone over each of these subintervals. However, I want to understand what condition on $f$, *in addition to given continuity*, is required for piecewise monotonicity.

So far I understand that continuity is not enough since it does not exclude the possibility of nowhere differentiable functions such as [this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) Also, requiring $f$ to be differentiable is not enough as it can be [everywhere differentiable but nowhere monotonic.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167323/everywhere-differentiable-function-that-is-nowhere-monotonic) What, then, is required to make a continuous function piecewise monotonic?

Comment: Doubt if this helps, but a continuous function is strictly monotone if and only if it is injective.

Answer (score 1):

What about the set of points where $f$ has local extrema is the finite sum of points and intervals?

Comment: Is this minimal requirement

Comment: It would be great if you could point a reference, in case this is well-known. The reason I care about "minimal additional requirement" is that piecewise monotonicity would follow, for example, if $f$ is analytic. But perhaps asking it to be analytic is too strong?

Comment: I don't have a reference. Clearly requesting $f$ to be analytic is to strong as $f$ is then infinitely differentibale which might not be the case for analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

A sufficient condition to have finite local extrema is to ask that each local extreme point is a strict one (since they are in a compact set [a,b] then they are finite)