# Is there a function that doesn't have a derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

I was wondering if such a function exist. I'm comfortable with derivatives of polynomial functions, and some other basic functions, but I'm wondering if there could exist a very complicated function that doesn't have a derivative.

Comment: Google "Weierstrass function".

Comment: Or, more simply, the absolute value function $|x|$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Related: [Are Continuous Functions Always Differentiable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/are-continuous-functions-always-differentiable) (And other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7923) might be also of interest.)

Comment: @mick, if my answer was useful, consider accepting it by clicking the gray tick on the left of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The commonly known example is the Weierstrass Function $f$, defined as
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\pi{k}^2x\right)}{\pi{k}^2}.$$

The $y=f(x)$ graph looks like this (and intuitively shows why it is differentiable nowhere):

[image: Graph of the Weierstrass Function]

Another example would be the Dirichlet Function $D$, defined as
$$D(x)=\begin{cases}1,\;\;x\in\mathbb{Q},\\0,\;\;x\in\mathbb{I}.\end{cases}$$

Its graph $y=D(x)$ would *look like* a pair of lines $\displaystyle{y=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}}$ (which of cousre is not a graph of any function), so is uninteresting to show. The interesting part is that $D$ is actually [discontinuous](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Discontinuous.html) *everywhere*, and therefore differentiable nowhere.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Weierstrass function is continuous everywhere.

Comment: does the Weierstrass function pass the vertical line test?

Comment: @mick Hint: It's a function.

Comment: @mick, any function passes the vertical line test. If you meant to ask about the Dirichlet Function $D$ instead, the source of confusion is clear: its graph only *looks* like a pair of parallel lines, but *actually* for every $x_0$ the line $x=x_0$ crosses only *one* of the “lines” of the graph  (and “goes through a hole in the second one”, if that adds intuition).