# Example of continuous non differentiable function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am looking for an Example of continuous non differentiable function in $R^2$

Comment: continuos and not differentible over the all domain?

Comment: Yes, over all domain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Continuous Functions Always Differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/are-continuous-functions-always-differentiable)

Comment: Thanks . got it

Comment: @DRPR Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classical patological example is the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).